# ng-hide and ng-show on dropdownlist angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

i am creating a web app in which i have 4 dropdownlist

```
<select>//calling dynamic data</select
<select>//calling dynamic data as per dropdown1</select
<select>//calling dynamic data as per dropdown2</select
<select>//calling dynamic data as per dropdown3</select
```

i want to make dropdown 2,3,4 uneditable, when user change the text of dropdown1(dropdown2) should be editable and when he change the text of downdown 2(dropdown3) should be visible and so on.

needed ur help

Comment: Do you mean at a time only one of the combo is editable

Comment: no when i change dropdown 1 dropdown 1 and 2 should be editable and 3 and for uneditable when i change dropdown2, dropdown 1,2,3 should be editable and 4 should be disable,

Comment: What should be the initial condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ng-disabled, and enable it upon ng-change event. I will explain this with just 2 dropdowns. you can extend this to as many as you want.

```
  <select ng-change="fruitselect(fruitname)" ng-model="fruitname" ng-init="fruitname = fruits[0]" >        
    <option ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" value="{{fruit}}">{{fruit}}</option>
   </select>

  <select ng-model="desertname" ng-disabled="isDessertDisabled">        
    <option ng-repeat="dessert in desserts" value="{{dessert}}">{{dessert}}</option>
   </select>
```

In the 2nd dropdown,note that `ng-disabled="isDessertDisabled"` . Now in the angular controller,

```
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange','banana', 'grapes', 'plum'];
$scope.isDessertDisabled = true;
$scope.desserts = ['apple pie', 'orange crush', 'red wine', 'plum cake']
$scope.fruitselect = function(fruitname){
  // some http call to get some desserts based on fruit name
  // $scope.desserts = response from $http call
  $scope.isDessertDisabled = false;
}
```

Now, although I have hardcoded the desserts array, in your case, it will bepopulated from http call. And then `isDessertDisabled` will be set to `false`. This will enable the 2nd dropdown with the fetched desserts values